# How do I remove the MobileMe icon in the menu bar?

Tags: mobileme, menu-bar

If I try to go to the settings in System Prefs > MobileMe, it asks for a username and password. Is there any way to remove the menu bar icon without needing to either login or create a MobileMe account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean this icon:

[image]

You must run iSync (by QuickSilver or Spotlight خق go into /Applications and double-click iSync) then uncheck "Show status in menu bar".

[image]

Comment: You can also go into /Applications and double-click iSync to open it - QuickSilver and/or Spotlight are unnecessary.

Comment: @kyle you are right, but I write the way I always use myself to open Application.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove menu icons by dragging them out of the menubar while holding the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-key.

This behavior does not work with icons from third party applications (e.g. Dropbox, Growl...).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from dragging it out as already mentioned, MobileMe specifically can also be set to show via the MobileMe System Preferences. Just untick the box stating Show MobileMe Sync Status in menu bar. This obviously only works if you have a MobileMe account.

[image]

Comment: That option is only available if you already have MobileMe configured

Comment: @Kyle. I am aware and stated so in my answer, however, I believe it is still valuable for someone that is Googling and may have a MobileMe account.